# how to fetch list class variables in java?

Tags: arraylist

class User{

String name;
int age;}

List listuser=new arrayList();

In abouve code how to access class memeber variables name and age using listuser ??
  Please help,
    Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to create some getters for name and age fields in User class.

```
       class User{

          String name; int age; //these are private by default so you cannot access them

          //create getters for the 2 members in order to access them outside of the User class
          public string getName() 
            {
                 return name;
            }

          public int getAge()
           {
                  return age;
              }
         }
```

then assuming you have already added users to the array list you can, for example:

```
         User user = (User)listuser.get(position); //cast the object at "position" to user.

          string name = user.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you should note is that List is of generic type like - List< E >

You need to specify that the **List is a list of which type**. In your case it is the list of type Users.

For a demo, here's how you can use List:

```
public class User {

    String name;
    int age;

    User(String nm, int age) {
        name = nm;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<User> listuser = new ArrayList<User>();

        listuser.add(new User("Foo", 21));
        listuser.add(new User("Bar", 22));

        System.out.println(listuser.get(0).name + " : " + listuser.get(0).age);
        System.out.println(listuser.get(1).name + " : " + listuser.get(1).age);
    }
}
```

Again, above I have used variables with default access.
Normally variables should be kept with private access, and in that case you need to specify getters and setters and then access those variables, just like Dan Dinu explained.